# How to create public and front end form through extension?

Tags: extension, webform-civicrm, forms, gsoc

I need to create a public and front-end form through an extension which is native extension that need to compatible with all CMSs like civicrm.com/civicrm/form civicrm.com/form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a form in an extension is mostly a matter of typing `civix generate:form`. It is [documented here](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addabasicwebform).